# EL and <c:out> prints empty string for null attributes but throws exception when the request is dispatched from servlet

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

My dispatcher servlet is :

```
 SampleModel model = new SampleModel();
 model.setModelName("someName");
 request.setAttribute("model", model);
 request.getRequestDispatcher("nulltester.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Here `SampleModel` class has only a single property named `modelName` . Snippet of JSP where the request is forwarded :

```
The undefined bar property is : ${model.bar} , <c:out value="${model.bar}">
```

If we hit the servlet and servlet then dispatches the request to the jsp , this code throws exception . But if we directly hit the JSP then we get the o/p without any exception ! Can anyone explain me why this happens ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no model attribute at all, the EL will evaluate `${model}` to null, and will stop the evaluation of `${model.bar}` there, returning an empty string.

If there is a model, it will evaluate `${model}` to your object and try to evaluate `${model.bar}` by calling `model.getBar()`, but won't find any such getter, which will lead to an exception.